# How to create views to views that leads to final destination content item?

Tags: views

I've been stuck with this problem for 2 weeks now, and I can't get it  working properly. It's so hard to explain that I made an infographic for it!

Basically I need a view that links from view to view until reaching final content items.

I know that it is a contextual filter setting or path, but I can't figure out the settings.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to users to log in to an external site, and verify how the site work.

Comment: I took the link off, can you put this back on please?

Comment: Hi Bruno, now it is a request for achieving functionality from a description, screenshot or other website; which is also not a good question as explained in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead edit the question to include your attempt(s) to achieve the desired functionality and be as complete as possible. What have you tried, what did you expect, what actually happened? If you have any code to include in the question, please add it. The more complete you are, the better we can formulate an answer.